# Программа с использованием рекурсии

Tags: python

Разработайте приложение с использованием рекурсивной функции вычисления количества цифр в десятичном натуральном числе а.( желательно в одну строку)Сомневаюсь в коде.Заранее спасибо.

```
def f(num, a=0):
    return f(num // 10, a + 1) if num else a
 
print(f(int(input())))`
```

Comment: А почему сомневаетесь в коде? С виду должен что нужно выдавать. Пробовали код на разных числах?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код прекрасно работает, может быть проблема на вещественных и отрицательных.

Решение при отрицательных числах

```
def f(num, a=0):
    return f(round(num * 0.1), a + 1) if num else a


print(f(int(input())))
```

Comment: По условию задачи число является десятичным, натуральным. Проблем нет.